# Why can't I partition my hard drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, partitioning

I'm trying to partition my hard drive, a WD My Passport, on my Mac. In disk utility the drive shows up but the partition option is greyed out. I've googled similar issues but I can't seem to find a fix. Any ideas? I've added a screenshot below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WRBJ.png)

Comment: What happens when you eject the HDD using the eject icon? Are you able to partition it once you no longer have the drive mounted?

Comment: Nope it's still greyed out.

Comment: How is this drive formatted? If it is formatted in NTFS, OSX may not be able to partition it. Backup your data first, then try to erase the drive. I will admit that it has been awhile since I tried anything like this in OSX, so this might be wrong; hence a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It was formatted as exFAT. However, I just erased it and made it OS X Extended and it's now letting me partition it. Seems weird that it can partition to exFAT but it can't partition it when it's already set up as exFAT? Either way, thanks!